# How to add an user and re set the root user in yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I like to do some things for the build-in users of my yocto project:

1.) set a password for root to "abc"

2.) set the root shell for ssh login form /bin/sh to /bin/bash

3.) add the user "customUser" with password "xyz"

Think a simple recipe can do this. So far I tried @ myUser.bb:

```
SUMMARY = "admin + user"
SECTION = "USR"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit extrausers useradd

# how to
# pw: abc
# at bash: usermod -p $(openssl passwd abc) root
# get a salted hash: openssl passwd abc
# one possible result: 1Cw5PHLy76ps2
# the command now looks: usermod -p 1Cw5PHLy76ps2 root

# set image root password
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p 1Cw5PHLy76ps2 root;"

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"

# password
# "xyz"
# openssl passwd xyz
# result: y5UyLBO4GNAwc

USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-u 1200 -d /home/customUser -r -s /bin/bash -p y5UyLBO4GNAwc customUser"

do_install_append () {
    install -d -m 755 ${D}${datadir}/customUser

    # The new users and groups are created before the do_install
    # step, so you are now free to make use of them:
    chown -R customUser ${D}${datadir}/customUser

    # groups
    # chgrp -R group1 ${D}${datadir}/customUser
}

FILES_${PN} = "${datadir}/*"

#ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"
```

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Well, what did your recipe achieve? What's your current problem?

Comment: the package created from the recipe contains only an empty dir with the name "customUser". Think the user creation/modification failed

Comment: Sure, but it was just those two modifications from your example. However, as you've likely noticed, this doesn't cover chaning the password of the root user. That's often accomplished by a sed -expression in a `ROOTFS_POSTPROC_COMMAND`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your example and made two small changes to get it to work.

First, I removed `inherit extrauser`, this isn't necessary when working with useradd. That made bitbaking the recipe fail; the username was invalid. I changed the username to `custom`, and everything builds fine.

When inspecting the resulting `myuser_1.0-r0.0_armv5e.ipk`, I can see that there are a preinstall script in `myuser_1.0-r0.0_armv5e.ipk/control.tar.gz/preinst` that will create your user.

Comment: Can you share the code? I was doing like you told and it's solving the problem. B.t.w.: at the root line the "-s /bin/bash" parameter is missing and for the custom user "-u 1200" is not needed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS` global in your main recipe.

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " useradd customUser1; \
                       useradd customUser2; \
                       usermod  -p 'Password_1' customUser1; \
                       usermod  -p 'Password_2' customUser2; \
                       usermod  -a -G sudo customUser1; \
                       usermod  -a -G sudo customUser2;"
```

Comment: This works, but I like to add/change the user at my local meta-layer conf.

Comment: Well, don't you have your own recipe? You should put it into that one, obviously it is in your private layer.

Comment: I have - it's called myUser.bb. I solved the problem by the help of @Anders

Comment: this only add user and while trying any command with sudo it give error ' user not in sudoers files, this incident will reported'.  @LPs

Comment: as root i can run any command but as another user, I can`t run any command I have to update bin path manually than I can execute command like 'ifconfig    wpa_supplicant'

Comment: It is `usermod  -P password user;`. Note the capital `-P` and no quqotes around password and user.

Comment: The latest versions of usermod don't support the `-P` option.  And `-p` is expecting the encrypted password hash.  You can use the `mkpasswd` command (part of Ubuntu's `whois` package) to generate password hashes.

Answer (score 3):

While upgrading our image from Yocto v3.x to v4.0 (Kirkstone), I had to change the following Yocto v3 bb image configuration:

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P temppw root;"
```

By first running the `mkpasswd` command to generate a required hash of the password.

```
printf "%q" $(mkpasswd -m sha256crypt temppw)
```

`mkpasswd` outputs the following for the password of "temppw":

```
\$5\$rRUXhVIMRx8vdFFp\$jLqPDLBkmHs4qj8DY9ggZ2YrsMzEVwRZuIJyTiKQLvB
```

I then modified my image bb file in Yocto v4 to be as follows:

```
inherit extrausers
PASSWD="\$5\$rRUXhVIMRx8vdFFp\$jLqPDLBkmHs4qj8DY9ggZ2YrsMzEVwRZuIJyTiKQLvB"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p '${PASSWD}' root;"
```

This is described in the latest Yocto Project docs here:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS

Comment: Alternative with openssl: `printf "%q" $(openssl passwd -5  temppw)` saves the `mkpasswd` dependency (not always installed)