# Yocto Jethro: how do I add user to sudoers list

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, sudoers, user-administration

I added a new user as follows

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd -P p@ssW0rd user1;"
```

I am trying to find how to add users to sudoers list. Is there a class like **extrausers**

**Update-1:**

In class `classes/extrausers.bbclass` I see `usermod` supported. Will the following work?

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd -P p@ssW0rd user1;\
                      usermod -aG sudo user1"
```

**Update-2:**

I tried adding `IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " sudo "` and

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd -P foobar -G sudo user1;"
```

But that does not help me in achieving the effect of adding user1 to sudoers list. I see following error when I do `sudo -v`

```
Sorry, user user1 may not run sudo on <machine-name>.
```

**Update-3:**

I found that the sudoers file has the sudo group commented as follows:
`# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL`
Hence the reason even adding `user1` to group `sudo` didn't help

Rather than adding `user1` to group `sudo` I adopted approach of adding a drop-in file under `/etc/sudoers.d/0001_user1` using `recipes-extended/sudo/sudo_1.8.14p3.bbappend`

```
do_install_append () {
    echo "user1 ALL=(ALL) ALL" > ${D}${sysconfdir}/sudoers.d/001_first
}
```

Now I need help in understanding which of following is a better approach in terms of security?

- uncomment `sudo` line in `/etc/sudoers` and adding `user1` to `/etc/sudoers`
- adding `user1` in `/etc/sudoers.d/001_first`

Comment: you could try to add the user to group "wheel" by default, which should be in sudoers already. like: useradd -P somepass -G wheel user1;

Comment: People mention it works there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043874/how-to-add-an-user-and-re-set-the-root-user-in-yocto .

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, When I try adding to wheel. I see wheel does not exist. `useradd: group 'wheel' does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two approaches to add an user with sudo capability

- Add user to sudo group and enable sudo group in /etc/sudoers
- Create a file under `${D}${sysconfdir}/sudoers.d/` and add the sudo rule for user there.

Now which approach is suitable for your distro is well answered in [/etc/sudoers vs /etc/sudoers.d/ file for enabling sudo for a user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375433/etc-sudoers-vs-etc-sudoers-d-file-for-enabling-sudo-for-a-user)